# How can I put a table next to another on pdf using jsPdf

Tags: javascript, jspdf, jspdf-autotable

I have a page with two graphics and two tables and I want to put those tables next to each other in a pdf, I'm using jsPDF, but when I put the second table it go right bellow the first one table, how can I put the table bellow?? 
Here is my code:

```
let canvas = document.getElementById('chart-s') as HTMLCanvasElement;
let canvas2 = document.getElementById('chart-m') as HTMLCanvasElement;
let canvasImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/jpg", 1.0);
let canvasImg2 = canvas2.toDataURL("image/jpg", 1.0);
let doc = new jsPDF();
doc.setFontSize(20);
doc.text(15, 15, `${moment().format("MMMM")} ${moment().format("YYYY")} - `+"Year");
doc.addImage(canvasImg, 'JPEG', 10, 20, 190, 70 );
doc.addImage(canvasImg2, 'JPEG', 10, 100, 190, 70 );


let tableOne = document.getElementById("table");
let res = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tableOne);
doc.autoTable({
  head: [[`${moment().subtract(1, "year").format("YYYY")}`, `${moment().format("YYYY")}`]], 
  body: res.data,
  margin: {top: 175, right: 10},
  tableWidth: 85
});
let tableTwo = document.getElementById("mtable");
let resd = doc.autoTableHtmlToJson(tableTwo);
doc.autoTable({
  head: [[`${moment().subtract(1, "year").format("YYYY")}`, `${moment().format("YYYY")}`]],
  body: resd.data,
  margin: {right: 50, bottom: 175},
  tableWidth: 85
});

doc.save('canvas.pdf');
```

Comment: Have you seen the multiple tables example in the jspdf-autotable github repo?

Comment: Sure I add some margins to try to put one next to another but it doesn't work

Comment: What does not work?